# Record is not getting deleted from datatable in LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, array, promises

I am trying to delete a record based on the row selection in data table in LWC. So when a row is selected, the record Id is pushed to the array `selectedIdsArray` but I am trying to pass it to the Apex method `deleteAccount` but it doesn't work and always end up in catch block. Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong?

**JavaScript:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track,api } from "lwc";
import deleteListVi from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteListView.deleteListVi";
import { deleteRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import deleteAccount from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteListView.deleteAccount";

export default class DeleteListView extends LightningElement {
  @track columns = [
    {
      label: "Account Name",
      fieldName: "Name"
    },

    {
      label: "Website",
      fieldName: "Website"
    }
  ];

  @track data;
  @api selectedIdsArray = [];
  @api recordId = [];

  @wire(deleteListVi)
  wireAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.data = data;
    } else if (data) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  }

  getrowId(event) {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable");
    var selected = selectedRows.getSelectedRows();


    for (const element of selected) {
      //console.log("elementid", element.Id);
      this.selectedIdsArray.push(element.Id);
    }
    console.log(this.selectedIdsArray);
  }

  handleClick(event) {

    console.log("selectedEvent " + this.selectedIdsArray);
    const recordId = this.selectedIdsArray;
    console.log('recordId '+ recordId );


    deleteAccount({accountIds: recordId})

      .then(result => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Success",
            message: "Account deleted",
            variant: "success"
          })
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error deleting record",
            message: "Error",
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }
}
```

**Apex:**

```
public with sharing class DeleteListView {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Account> deleteListVi(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Website FROM Account LIMIT 10];

    } 

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void deleteAccount(Id[] accountIds){
        delete [SELECT Id,Name, Website FROM Account where Id IN: accountIds];

    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**

[image]

**Edit 2** - When I select two records, it duplicates the 1st record again and the end result is a total of 3 records. I am confused as to why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: What error you are getting in catch block ? as you said records are passing to selectedArray property, It is always good to check the apex log to see if any trigger is causing this delete event.

Comment: @brahmajitammana I have attached an image. Issue is that the recordId is able to fetch the Id of the selected row but the question is whether it is passing to the Apex correctly. I have also deactivated all triggers and related triggers.

Comment: The LWC and APEX code seems to be fine, but the delete operation may also fail due to referential integrity issues or permission issues. Does the user (that you are logged in as) have any object level permission restrictions for deletion? Also, are there any triggers or restrictions on possible child objects? Note that the delete operation on a parent record will fail if the child record deletion causes exception. Try to catch the exception stack trace in apex code.

Comment: @arut I figured out the issue. It couldn't delete as it has some associated contacts and opportunities along with it. It's working when I select an Account with no opportunities and contacts but the issue now is that when I select multiple records it adds twice to the array. I am not sure why this is happening. I have attached the image.

Comment: I guess the function `getrowId(event)` is wired as onrowaction handler. In this code, you are fetching the entire lightning data table and getting all the selected rows every time. Hence, its adding duplicate records. I bet if you selected 3 records, then you will have 6 entries in the array (3 entries for first record selected, 2 entries for second record selected and 1 entry for last record selected). You need to change the code inside this method. BTW, you can just use `event.detail.row.Id` to get the record ID inside this JS handler function.

Comment: Thanks @arut yes you are correct. Do you have any idea how I can prevent those duplicates?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comments, `event.detail.row.Id` should get you the record ID for the row on which the JS handler was triggered. You can simply push this into `this.selectedIdsArray`, instead of the code you have at the moment. Also, check the user action (uncheck or check) and accordingly pop or push out of the `this.selectedIdsArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the selectedRows gives all the selected records in every selection.

Either you need to write a logic to check if array contains the id before push or use **map** method which creates new array and set all values everytime.

You can try updating your getrowId function to something like this.

```
getrowId(event) {
   this.selectedIdsArray = event.detail.selectedRows.map((element) => {
       return element.Id;
   });
}
```

Comment: `this.selectedIdsArray = event.detail.selectedRows.map(element => element.Id );` works, too. No need for a return statement if you drop the function block syntax.

Comment: agree @sfdcfox thanks